# Qual a melhor forma de enviar dados action(formulario) ou submit do jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Existe hoje algum padrão para enviar dados de formulário? Usar jquery e eliminar o  action(formulario) ou validar com jquery e enviar os dados usando action(formulario).

Comment: Provavelmente essa pergunta será fechada, pelo fato de não está clara o suficiente e por ser ampla demais. Tente explicar melhor o problema em si, o que tentou e o que pretende fazer.

Comment: marconi, Eu quero enviar dados para outra pagina. qual a melhor forma de fazer? usando o jquery ou usando action do formulário.

Comment: Não existe a melhor forma. Isso pode varias de cada aplicação e necessidade. Eu por exemplo gosto muito de utilizar jQuery e passar os dados serializados. Mas se for necessário enviar de outra forma eu envio!

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma melhor forma mas no caso de envio de um formulário é prudente usar o action form porque se o usuário tiver qualquer erro em relação ao Javascript (ex: javascript desativado) será impossível enviar seu formulário.